# Turning airplane mode doesnt turn off VPN automatically?

Tags: swift, networking, ios11

So I am using `NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable` by `Alamofire` to check for network connection. In iOS 10 and earlier, this seems to work well just by turning off airplane mode. But in iOS 11, it seems that I have to manually turn off VPN as well. I do not have anymore iOS 10 devices so I didnt have the chance to retry on iOS 10, but does anyone have the same issue as me?

Steps to reproduce:

1) Use ANY common `Reachbility` or `Alamofire` class.

2) On VPN & WIFI.

3) Set iPad to airplane mode. (Without turning off VPN)

4) Check connection using and it seems like isReachable is still being returned as `true`.